# moving image behind another image with transparent holes

Tags: c#, winforms

`int[,] board = new int[6, 7];
        PictureBox boardpb = new PictureBox();
        PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[42];
        Image table, red, blue;
        int c = 0;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        red = Properties.Resources.red; red = (Image)(new Bitmap(red, new Size(110, 110)));
        blue = Properties.Resources.blue; blue = (Image)(new Bitmap(blue, new Size(110, 110)));
        table = Properties.Resources.Board; table = (Image)(new Bitmap(table, new Size(700, 700)));

        boardpb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        boardpb.Image = table;
        boardpb.Size = table.Size;
        boardpb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        boardpb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Human_Play);
        this.Controls.Add(boardpb);
    }

    void PlayCircle(int x, int y, Image im) //plays a red/blue circle in the corresponding (y,x) position
    {
        pb[c] = new PictureBox();
        pb[c].Location = new Point((int)(-2 + 98.8 * x), (int)(83 + 94.4 * y));
        pb[c].Image = im;
        pb[c].Size = im.Size - new Size(10, 10);
        pb[c].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pb[c].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Human_Play);
        boardpb.Controls.Add(pb[c]);
        c++;
    }

    int Y(int x) // gives the lowest empty space in the column, or -1 if the column is full.
    {
        for (int y = 5; y >= 0; y--)
            if (board[y, x] == 0) return y;
        return -1;
    }

    void Human_Play(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x, y;
        x = (Cursor.Position.X) / 99;
        if ((x <= 6) && (x >= 0))
        {
            y = Y(x);
            if (y != -1)
            {
                PlayCircle(x, y, red);
                board[y, x] = -1;
            }
        }
    }`
```

i am making a connect 4 game to my uni project using WinForms C#. while trying to make the pieces fall into the board, they were like moving under the board image hiding the board lines behind them.
Any idea how to make the pieces images move behind the board, but still able to be seen through the board holes (like the picture in the following link)?
PS: the board and the 2 pieces picture do have transparent background.
thanks in advance ^^
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/connect4.gif
UPDATE: i added the code. (table,red,blue are 3 images in my resources)
How to edit this code so the pieces fall down behind the board instead of just popping in ?

Comment: Please describe something more about your coding approach to solve the problem ... thanx

Comment: It occurs to me that you might need just 2 animations one for red and one for black passing through a cell.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: the solution u gave me sounded pretty good but i didnt try it yet i was focusing on other functions in my project much important than this animation. Thank you very much :D @TaW

Comment: Well, if you ever come back to it and have questions, do ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Draw all the graphics using the GDI+ commands `FillRectangle` and `FillEllipse`.
- Use Controls that hold Bitmaps of the grid and the pieces.

I guess you are trying to go for the second option.

However in **Winforms** transparency is only supported for **nested** controls. The direct approach will however overlap the controls and therefore not work.

Instead you would need to **nest** the bottom control in the playing field and the every layer above in the one below. Since you only need one layer above the piece, namely the grid, you would have to nest the grid in the piece.

This is possible, but **not quite natural**, as for this to work you must make the piece large enough to hold the whole grid and at every position it will take during the animation. So if you set it at the start of each move it will have to be twice the height of the board and its full width.

Then in a `Timer.Tick` you move the piece down and the grid nested within it up until the piece has found its place.

Finally to draw the piece into the `Image` of the board `PictureBox`. Make the `BackgroundImage` show the same grid so you can simply hide the piece before setting it up for the next move..

So you would start a move in column c by drawing a red or a black circle at position (`c, height * 2`) in a bitmap of size (`board.width, board.height*2`) and assign it to a `PictureBox movingPiece`.

You have prepared one bitmap holding the grid and assinged it as the Image of a `PictureBox grid`. Now you nest the three controls:

```
movingPiece.Parent = board;
grid.Parent = movingPiece;
```

In the Tick you move the pice doen and the grid it contains up:

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    movingPiece.Top++;
    grid.Top--;
    // if finalposition etc..
}
```

- Option two is simpler imo: Create the grid in the `BackgroundImage`. Draw the set pieces into the `Image`. And animate in the `Tick&Paint` event by filling one Circle and one Rectangle at the overlapping position.

I would go for this; it is not more natural to understand and much less pixels get moved so it probably is faster too..

Comment: ...at least 2 options.  How about recording a disc passing through a REAL connect 4 cell in front of a green screen.  this fragment could be used as many times over as is necessary ...

Comment: LOL, yes this sounds like another nice one ;-)

Comment: i cant do neither of these. my board is not rectangular,it is an image. and in the first option, the big-sized picturebox works only for one piece cz it would hide the others.

Comment: None of your reasons apply to either soution. If your board is not rectangular, what is it? You need to show us! Only one piece can move at any time right? So all previous pieces can be drawn into a bitmap.. and since is is (almost) completely transparent it won't anything..

Comment: Looking at your code I see no animation. You want that, though, right? during the anmation you can paint the relevant portion of the grid on top of the PBox..There is a DrawImage overload which will help you, provided your board image has indeed transparent holes.

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the board after the pieces.

If you use an image for the board, just be sure that there is transparency channel. You can find more explanation [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172507%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

If you use vectorial line drawing for the board, there will be no issue as long as you draw nothing in the holes.

Comment: To speed up the drawing process, Tarek could draw the board just once and restrict/mask the pixels of the pieces to those coordinates where the board image is transparent.

Comment: i cant draw the board after the pieces bcz they must fall down when the user clicks a column of the board.
i checked the msdn link and it worked nice but i cant move the pieces from top to bottom of the board if used that code.
the piece should be inside a picturebox

Comment: It might be helpful for us to see the exact assignment because you may be constrained to use a particular technique.  However, what Axel means is that as you draw and redraw the disc falling you finish each redraw with a redraw of the gridlines.  That way the gridlines will always appear to be in front.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

1. Draw the board (or load from image), with OR WITHOUT transparency.  Most controls in WinForms (form, panel, picturebox, etc.) support either a BackgroundImage or some other bulk image load as your base layer.
2. Draw each piece appropriately ON TOP of the board, but clip/mask/manipulate the circular pieces so that only the correct portion of the circle shows through the "holes" in the board.  You should just have to know the position of the holes in the board image to calculate this, and it will make the pieces appear as if they are "within" the board, like they would in reality.

Comment: that would be so hard since my board has circular holes :/    I just want to move the piece down behind the board

Comment: Then you could do the opposite: draw all the pieces first (as normal circles), and overlay the board.  I know this was your original question, but wasn't sure how to do it - there seems to be a workable example [here](http://lextendo.blogspot.com/2012/10/transparent-picturebox-overlay-in.html) that uses parent/child pictureboxes to achieve layering, although haven't used this particular technique before.

Comment: @TarekGhamrawi - actually, it seems to be *fairly* straightforward to exclude regions from the board - in your case, excluding the "holes", making them transparent.  You might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039699/system-drawing-invert-region-build-out-of-path). I think if you draw the clipped image or some inverted version of it (with "holes" left undrawn) you can get what you want.